# Does the Zebra_Database MySQL wrapper protect against SQL injection?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-injection

I am considering using a MySQL wrapper named Zebra_Database found here:

http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-database/

Can someone tell by the code if this protects against SQL injection or are there further steps I should take to protect myself?

Thanks!!

Comment: It encourages the use of prepared statements, which are not susceptible to sql injection. From the front page "It encourages developers to write maintainable code and provides a better default security layer by encouraging the use of prepared statements, where parameters are automatically escaped."

Comment: So basically that just means to wrap each input with mysqli_real_escape_string?

Comment: No, it means you should use prepared statements, which are not susceptible to SQL injection to begin with.

Comment: @benjamin-gruenbaum Thank you.  I'll mark this an the answer if you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It encourages the use of prepared statements, which are not susceptible to SQL injection.

From the front page of Zebra_Database:

> It encourages developers to write maintainable code and provides a better default security layer by encouraging the use of prepared statements, where parameters are automatically escaped.

Which means you should use prepared statements, which are not susceptible to SQL injection to begin with. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) about the usage of prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

It encourages the use of prepared statements - the same limited version used by mysqli - so, it offers no 100% protection.
It uses some sort of query builder - so, it makes your SQL too inflexible (and - therefore - insecure again).

Personally I wouldn't use it, but for starter it's better than "wrap each input with mysqli_real_escape_string" anyway.